# Evaluate a numerical integral

Tags: numerical-integration

This is problem 2.6 of Griffiths but I want to get the numerical integral of

```
ψxt = NIntegrate[Sin[a k]/ k * E^(I (k*x - ℏ*k^2*t/(2 m))), {k, -∞, ∞}]
```

But Mathematica can't calculate the integral in the boundaries. What should I do?

Comment: For a numeric integration you must assign numeric values to all of the constants, then the integration can be done.

Answer (score 3):

Mathematica can evaluate this integral analytically

```
Integrate[
 Sin[a k]/k E^(I*k*x - ℏ*k^2*t/(2 m)), {k, -∞, ∞}, 
 Assumptions -> Element[a | t | m | ℏ, Reals] && t > 0 && m > 0 && ℏ > 0]
```

$$\frac{\pi}{2}\left(\text{erf}\left(\frac{a-x}{\sqrt{\frac{2t \hbar }{m}}}\right)+\text{erf}\left(\frac{a+x}{\sqrt{\frac{2 t \hbar }{m}}}\right)\right)$$